# Book about time-travel to a future where a leader has cloned himself

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

I read this book maybe 10 years ago. I'll try and piece as much of it as I can below:

- Protagonist is a male school student.
- He is approached by someone and requested to go with them to the future where the (president/prime minister?) has cloned himself and abusing his power.
- In this future, there is a device that people can use to learn skills instantly (a helmet, with various skill cards if I remember correctly)? The protagonist uses this to learn how to swim, as the future character's identity he is assuming can swim well.
- Whilst he has this device, he comes across a (Jedi mind powers?) card that is mentioned to be unsafe/unpredictable, but he uses it anyway.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Great start. Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and see if you can remember anything else.

Comment: Thanks @amflare. Looking at the guide, I can't recall anything new at the moment, but I'll be sure to edit the question if I do.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably wrong, but I am reminded of *Worlds of the Imperium* by Keith Laumer. Rather than the future, the protagonist is taken to a parallel world where a political dictator is his other self.

Comment: Not the book I was thinking of, but looks like an interesting read! Thanks for sharing.